# Tiny stub of bogus code purely for the purpose of setting a breakpoint (that doesn't create a compiler warning)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This is trivial question but find myself thinking it all the time - often when debugging, I want to break right after a certain line of code executes, and rather than putting the breakpoint on the next line of code (which may be a ways down due to large comment blocks, or putting it on the last line of code and then hitting F10 to go over it after it breaks, I have this urge to put a short stub line on which I will set my breakpoint.

In VBA I'd use DoEvents for this, the shortest thing in c# I've found that doesn't create an annoying compiler warning (the variable 'x' is declared but never used) is:

```
int x = 1; x++;
```

Is this about as good as you can get, or is there some other obvious approach to this I'm not aware of?

Note: I am aware of suppressing warnings via:

```
#pragma warning disable 0168    // get rid of 'variable is never used warning'
```

...but find it sporadically doesn't work.

Comment: If you're inserting the code specifically during the debugging session, consider using [Debugger.Break](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  This makes it very clear why you're adding the line (if it gets left in by mistake.)  'Useless code' for this purpose is likely to be confusing to future maintainers.

Comment: You are helping too much.  Just set the breakpoint on the first line of the comment.  This doesn't faze the debugger, it automatically moves it at runtime.

Comment: You could always use an empty *block* of statements: `{ }`. That seems to me the simplest way to achieve what you are asking.

Comment: I usually do it with a 
    string blah = "";

Comment: @InBetween - Although I accepted a different answer, just saw your { } comment now - that is perfect, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For debugging purposes, what I always do is use `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()`. In practice, it's just like inserting a break point on a statement but is much easier to determine its function after the fact, and is maintained through source control between users and systems. It doesn't clutter your Breakpoints window. It also, helpfully enough, will not trigger when running in Release mode, allowing you to place these in areas of critical importance, and leave them in without harming your customer releases.

*As an alternate suggestion, following **InBetween**'s comment:*

If, instead, you are looking for a "harmless" statement that you can simply set a breakpoint on when you desire, Thread.Sleep(0) should be similar enough to your anecdotal VBA solution to suffice for your debugging purposes.

> Thread.Sleep(0).  This tells the system you want to forfeit the rest
>   of the thread’s timeslice and let another, waiting, thread run.

-- http://blogs.msmvps.com/peterritchie/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program/

This would be a less ideal solution in my mind than my first suggestion, but it may be more what you're looking for.

Comment: This is generally the best option but the way the OP is asking the question it seems to me that he's looking for a way to include harmless code where he can set a breakpoint when convenient. `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` will always act as a break point which obliges you to comment it out / in as needed, which is more of a pain.

Comment: Hmm, ok; I'll expand my answer.

Comment: Just for clarity...if you accidentally compile to exe in debug mode and deploy, a Debugger.Break() **will** break, correct?  If so, I think the thread.Sleep or DoNothing() are probably superior.

Answer (score 2):

So you need to

- write code which does nothing, but can accept a breakpoint, and
- tell other programmers that it does nothing (so they don't try and "fix" it).

Make a function which does nothing:

```
// Call it anywhere, so you can put a breakpoint on the code
public static void DoNothing()
{
    // Any code which does nothing here
}
```

Then call it:

```
... some code ...
DoNothing();
... other code ...
```

Comment: I marked the other answer as correct, but in practice I think I might actually prefer this one, thank you.